# Column type not defined while upgrading from slick 2.1 to slick 3.2 in scala

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, slick-2.0

The following block of code was working on slick 2.1 but when I upgraded the slick version, the code is not working.

```
import slick.lifted.Column

trait IntegerId {
  def id: Column[Int]
}
```

The error received: `Cannot resolve symbol Column`

Is there any alternative or workaround for this issue?

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: According to the [2.1.0 docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#package), `Column` was the base type for `ConstColumn`, `LiteralColumn`, `ParameterColumn`, `TypedCase`, and `TypedCaseWithElse`. [In 3.2.1](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/api/index.html#package) only `ConstColumn` and `LiteralColumn` still exist and there is no `Column` base class that they share.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough context to really answer your question. Given the fact that [Table.column](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.2.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/relational/RelationalProfile.scala#L134)  is defined as

```
def column[C](n: String, options: ColumnOption[C]*)(implicit tt: TypedType[C]): Rep[C] = {
```

what you need might be

```
import slick.lifted.Rep

trait IntegerId {
  def id: Rep[Int]
}
```